# Pentaho: How to read SQL result row by row to execute one by one?

Tags: pentaho, kettle, data-integration

i built a simple transform for select rows data from table in the database using Table Input.

i know that Table Input return all result one time. but what i need to do is to get result row by row and continue the process, then return back to the next row and so on.

so any ideas please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from `Pentaho` Forums :

> Build a job, and let the first transformation retrieve all the rows
>   via Table Input. Use a "Copy rows to result" step to save the result.
>   Create a second transformation configured for single row execution -
>   see advanced transformation settings. Use "Get rows from result" to
>   start single row processing.

in addition to :

[Transformation Executor](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Transformation+Executor)